# Cron error after upgrade to 4.7.1

Tags: upgrade, cron-job, error, 4.7

Upgraded from 4.6.11 to 4.7.1 and now this this error when running /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Function
>   "is_admin()" is missing, even though WordPress is the user framework.'
>   in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php:261 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(219):
>   CRM_Utils_System_Base->theme('PEAR_Error('DB Error: insuf...', -26, 16, Array, '
>   [nativecode=10...') #5
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564):
>   DB_Error->DB_Error(-26, 16, Array, ' [nativec in
>   /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php
>   on line 261

Comment: How are you running this?  Utilizing the run manually page, I'm able to run the jobs without issue.  However, curl and wget are failing with username/password errors and/or key errors, while php is complaining of deprecated # comment marks, that need to be re-written to ;.

Comment: I got this same error in Joomla 3.4.8. Upon clearing caches and reset paths, now completely broken. Blank pages.

Comment: Running a script with this command: /usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u mysqluser -p mysqlpass -e Job -a execute

i think the primary error is "DB Error: Insufficient Permissions" - however, i can log into MySql with the same credentials manually without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

On a WordPress site with CiviCRM 4.6.10 I had the same problem but switching from the "URL" to the "CLI" method of executing cron fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An issue has been filed for this in the CiviCRM bug tracker.

See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18514

Answer (score 0):

I see from the above that you are using the php cli method.   The credentials that it is looking for is a CMS User (WordPress) with sufficient permissions in CiviCRM to run the jobs.

I just tested on 4.7.8 CiviCRM with WP 4.5.2 with the following syntax

```
/usr/local/php56/bin/php /home/user/htdocs/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u cronuser -p somepassword -e Job -a execute
```